# SecurtiyAgent process offload work to SecurityAgentHelper

Tags: macos, login, login-screen, authentication

Projects like Nomad-login (or nowadays Jamf-connect) use to modify the mechanism list in `system.login.console` authorizationRight.

I see that non-privileged mechanisms runs by SecurityAgent process, but it can sometimes delegate another process called SecurityAgentHelper which is an xpc service.

I wonder if the role of process SecurityAgentHelper is to serve as fallback to SecurityAgent and under what conditions does it offload task for the helper process.

Can someone explain this design to me?

Answer (score 1):

## Stability and Privilege Separation

XPC services are used to isolate sections of a process that require specific security considerations. `SecurityAgent` will pass `SecurityAgentHelper` work that needs to be isolated. It will not act as a fallback; this is not the intention of XPC services.

See Apple's [Creating XPC Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) for a detailed explanation of XPC Service's role and design:

> The XPC Services API, part of libSystem, provides a lightweight mechanism for basic interprocess communication integrated with Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) and launchd. The XPC Services API allows you to create lightweight helper tools, called XPC services, that perform work on behalf of your application.
>
> There are two main reasons to use XPC services: privilege separation and stability.